# Gap between 2 lines in table cell when image inserted - XHTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a table created in XTMl, and I have two lines in table cell, for example:

```
Firstname
Surname
```

In the same cell I would like to place the image on the right. When I insert it like `<img>`
I get gap between two lines like this:

```
Firstname

Surname
```

Often the image is placed under second line. Why is that happening, and what I should do to prevent it ?

```
<td><strong>Name<br />Lastname<a href="google.com"><img src="images/1.gif" alt="img" /></a></strong></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css style "white-space:nowrap;" to the td.

Answer (score 0):

In the image style try adding "float:right" to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The image element is an inline-block element, which means that it's a block that is part of the inline content. When you put the image tag in there, it's part of the second line of text. The second line will get high enough to hold the height of the image, that is causing the space between the texts.

You can take the image out of the inline content by making it a block element, and you can place it to the right by floating it.

Put the image tag first in the cell, and add the CSS style `float:right;` to it. By making it a floating element you also automatically make it a block element.

Comment: But wouldn't I then have additional space, since I am using block element ?

Comment: @Nicol: Where would that extra space be? The image will float to the right, and the text will flow around it if it doesn't fit to the left of it.

Comment: I know what you say but it is not working...   I hve:                    <td><strong>Name<br />Lastname<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/1.gif" alt="img" /></a></strong></td> I added as you suggested float to right, and I also have a space betwwen the first and second line..

Comment: @Nicol: Here is an example. As you have a link around the image I put the float on that instead, otherwise some browsers may act up. http://jsfiddle.net/wWjcg/